# Ignore deprecated classes on Sonar alaysis

Tags: deprecated, sonarqube

We have Sonar running on the nightly build, I'm starting tweaking it to satisfy our needs. Currently there many violations on deprecated classes (this classes are no longer maintained, intended to be deleted soon).

What I want to do is to run Sonar on supported classes, i.e. all  classes but deprecated.

To have a cleaner issues report.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the sonar.exclusions property to tell SonarQube which classes to exclude from analysis. Here's a link that you might also find useful

[Narrowing the focus of analysis](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreFiles)